# react-router-dom url changed but no view update (with withRouter infinity refresh)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, mobx

I'm using react-router-dom: "4.3.1" with mobx, and try just redirect to my route.
After reading a lot similar questions I can't resolve this problem.

I've tried storing in state some flag and according to it use .
Tried use

```
 this.props.history.push('....');
 this.forceUpdate();
```

Tried wrap component with withRouter before mobx decorators and after.
With withRouter my component start inifinity rerender and my componentDidMound call api infinity times. (if I wrap after mobx)
I've tried many variants and this library still don't work properly.

```
// my main component
 <Router basename={`/${baseName}`}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      ...
    </Provider>
  </Router>
// my routes
 <Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={ComponentA} />
    <Route exact path="/a" component={ComponentB} />
    <Route path="/a/:id" component={ComponentA} />
    <Redirect to="/home" /> // this works normal
  </Switch>
```

Usually react-router-dom just change browser url, but no component rerender, but with withRouter this start infinity api calls. How should I use this library with redirecting in any cases?

Comment: on which route changes no view updates?

Comment: upload more code, not getting from this

Comment: I've added example of code which don't work. There no any specific code

Answer (score 0):

```
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Col, PageHeader, Row, Well } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CompanyNew from './CompanyNew';
import { Company, InjectedProps } from '../../types';

interface CompanyNewPageProps extends InjectedProps {
  history: HIstory
}

@inject('store')
@observer
export class CompanyNewPage extends React.Component<CompanyNewPageProps> {
  public get injected() {
    return this.props as InjectedProps;
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <>
        <PageHeader>Create new Company</PageHeader>
        <Col className="col-lg-12">
          <Row>
            <Well>
              <CompanyNew handleClose={this.itemAdded} />
            </Well>
          </Row>
        </Col>
      </>
    );
  }

  public itemAdded = (company: Company) => {
    this.props.history.push(`/companies/${company.id}`);
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
}

export default CompanyNewPage;
```

there example, this small component which is wrapper over another component, and after creating instance redirect to it. Item already exists on redirecting